# Unable to authorize using bearer token using swagger-ui-express

Tags: node.js, swagger

Currently trying to add swaggerUI to my nodejs project and having some issues with the token authentication portion of it.

I have all the routes added. And currently if I want to test an endpoint on Postman that requires token authentication, it fails because I am unable to supply a token in the header of the request.

[what I see on swaggerUI currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkLGV.png)

There seems to be the 'authentication' icon after adding securitySchemes under components in the swagger.js file, and I included a configuration for BearerAuth. My swagger.js file looks like this:

```
const swaggerJsdoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");

// swagger options for API documention
const options = {
  definition: {
    openapi: "3.0.3",
    info: {
      servers: [
        {
          url: "http://localhost:3020",
        },
      ],
    },
    basePath: "/social",
    tags: [
      { name: "Auth", description: "Social Auth APIs" },
      { name: "Content", description: "Social Content APIs" },
    ],
    schemes: ["http"],
    consumes: ["application/json"],
    produces: ["application/json"],
  },
  components: {
    securitySchemes: {
      BearerAuth: {
        type: "http",
        scheme: "bearer",
      },
    },
  },
  apis: ["./routes/*.js"],
};

const specs = swaggerJsdoc(options);

module.exports = {
  specs,
};
```

An example of how I am referring to use the authentication method defined in securitySchemas:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /social/content/:
 *   get:
 *     description: retrieves the top level post for the current week selected by the coach for the current team
 *     security:
 *       - BearerAuth: []
 *     tags:
 *       - Content
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Retrieved post success
 *       400:
 *         description: Bad request error
 *       401:
 *         description: Access token is missing or invalid
 *       500:
 *         description: Internal server error
 */
```

In my index.js file:

```
// swagger libs
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
const swaggerOptions = require("./utils/swagger");


// swagger docs
app.use(
  "/social/api-docs",
  swaggerUi.serve,
  swaggerUi.setup(swaggerOptions.specs, {
    explorer: true,
  })
);
```

There are more lines of code in the index.js file, however I only showed the ones added for the configuration of swaggerUI.

For the routes that don't require authentication, I am seeing the responses fine in my backend server when testing on swaggerUI, but for the endpoints that require token authentication, it returns back to me an error of UnauthorizedError, no authorization token was found.

Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated, and if any more info is needed, I can try to provide.

**EDIT:**
Found the solution, and was a formatting error. I need to move the components object inside definition object and that solved all the authorization issues, and able to persist token authorization. Thank you!

Comment: _"There seems to be the 'authentication' icon after adding securitySchemes"_ - click that icon, it should open a dialog where you can enter the bearer token. Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: @Helen that button is not clickable, I forgot to mention.

Comment: Is there a green "Authorize" button above the endpoint list? [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JLxF.png). If yes, is it clickable?

Comment: @Helen Unfortunately nope, there isn't a green "Authorize" button like the one shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

It was a formatting error. I needed to move the components object inside definition object and that solved all the authorization issues, and able to persist token authorization. Thank you!